# ASP.NET MVC4 Web API MediaTypeFormatter Converter to convert XElement to JSON

Tags: c#, xml, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am building an API in ASP.NET MVC4 Web API, and one of my actions returns XML (currently in the form of an XElement). I have no control of the data, I am just passing it on. There is no standard object that I can de-serialize it to.

```
public Task<XElement> Get( string queryName, string query )...
```

What I want to do is use a MediaTypeFormatter to convert that to JSON if it is requested as such. I have started writing the MediaTypeFormatter and hooked it up, but when I call the "Get" on the controller, it calls

```
protected override bool CanWriteType( Type type )
{
    return true;
}
```

in the MediaTypeFormatter, but never gets as far as the OnWriteToStreamAsync method. The result is just the XML as a string, e.g.

```
"<testXmlHere\/>"
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this up?

Thanks

Comment: Why is your API returning a Task?

Comment: It does that to enable async execution. There are a number of articles on it, but pretty much the whole stack is designed for async execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom formatter is probably inserted in the formatters list after the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` in the formatters collection. That formatter can write `XElement`, and it does so by writing the XML representation as a JSON string (whether this is a good or bad idea is another discussion). When adding your formatter to the collection, use the `Insert` instead of the `Add` method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(
    0, new MyCustomMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild suggestion... First create an HttpResonponse message and set the content to whatever data you're retrieving. Try creating a custom action filter (System.Web.HttpFilters.ActionFilterAttribute) and implement the OnActionExecuted method.

In your method, get the respective HttpRequest and HttpResponse objects from the HttpActionExecutedContext. You can retrieve the Accept header from the HttpRequest and your data from the HttpResponse. Format your data based on the Request's Accept header if necessary  and reassign it to the Response content.

You get where I'm coming from??

Answer (score 0):

```
    public HttpResponseMessage<SensorUpdate> Post(int id)
    {
        SensorUpdate su = new SensorUpdate();
        su.Id = 12345;            
        su.Username = "SensorUpdateUsername";
        su.Text = "SensorUpdateText";
        su.Published = DateTime.Now;


        HttpResponseMessage<SensorUpdate> response = new HttpResponseMessage<SensorUpdate>(su, 
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Fyi - The HttpResponseMessage<T> object has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

MVC4 Quick Tip #3–Removing the XML Formatter from ASP.Net Web API

in Global.asax:
add the line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

like so:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
    }
```